# Nested objects and ng-models in Angular-JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am looking for solution for a problem which might not exist the way I am trying to do it. So if anyone can help me with the best way of doing this.

ISSUE:

I have the following input field:

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="quote" ng-model="person.quotes.quote">
 <input type="text" placeholder="author" ng-model="person.author">
 <input type="text" placeholder="category" ng-model="person.category">
```

And I have the following object:

```
$scope.person = {
author: $scope.author,
category: $scope.category,
quotes: [{quote: $scope.quote}]
};
```

I am trying to get the value person.quote into the array of quotes. But I can't seem to do it.

REASON:

The reason why I am doing this is that when a user fills the input fields and clicks on a button the values are saved into the $scope.person object. And that I push that entire object to my firebase API. I want to maintain the structure of my $scope.person object as I have described in my javascript the same in my firebase API. I can easily push author and category but the nested quotes objects are not being pushed.

THE ERROR I GET:

Error: Firebase.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'quotes.0.quote'

Thanks in advance and if this information is not enough please let me know so i can provide with more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the property `quotes` from object `person` is array.

```
ng-model="person.quotes[0].quote"
```

Comment: Ah! so simple. I knew it was something small. Thank you so much!